# Scala conditional accumulation

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a function that extracts from a given string "placeholders" delimited by $ character.

Processing the string:

```
val stringToParse = "ignore/me/$aaa$/once-again/ignore/me/$bbb$/still-to-be/ignored
```

the result should be:

```
Seq("aaa", "bbb")
```

What would be a Scala idiomatic alternative of following implementation using `var` for toggling accumulation?

```
import fiddle.Fiddle, Fiddle.println
import scalajs.js
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

@js.annotation.JSExportTopLevel("ScalaFiddle")
object ScalaFiddle {
  // $FiddleStart
  
  
  val stringToParse = "ignore/me/$aaa$/once-again/ignore/me/$bbb$/still-to-be/ignored"
  
  class StringAccumulator {
    
    val accumulator: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]
    val sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder("")
    var open:Boolean = false
    
    def next():Unit = {
      if (open) {
        accumulator.append(sb.toString)
        sb.clear
        open = false
      } else {
        open = true
      }
    }
    
    def accumulateIfOpen(charToAccumulate: Char):Unit = {
      if (open) sb.append(charToAccumulate)
    }
    
    def get(): Seq[String] = accumulator.toList
  }
  
  def getPlaceHolders(str: String): Seq[String] = {
    val sac = new StringAccumulator
  
    str.foreach(chr => {
      if (chr == '$') {
        sac.next()
      } else {
        sac.accumulateIfOpen(chr)
      }
    })
    
    sac.get
  }
  
  println(getPlaceHolders(stringToParse))
  // $FiddleEnd
}
```

Comment: To be clear, in this example you want all strings in between the matching $? Can you post the code you currently have, so we have some idea what direction you've started?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example using var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll present two solutions to you. The first is the most direct translation of what you've done. In Scala, if you hear the word `accumulate` it usually translates to a variant of `fold` or `reduce`.

```
 def extractValues(s: String) =
 {
    // We can combine the functionality of your boolean and StringBuilder by using an Option
    s.foldLeft[(ListBuffer[String],Option[StringBuilder])]((new ListBuffer[String], Option.empty))
                  {
                    //As we fold through, we have the accumulated list, possibly a partially built String and the current letter
                    case ((accumulator,sbOption),char) =>
                    {
                      char match
                      {
                        //This logic pretty much matches what you had, adjusted to work with the Option
                        case '$' =>
                        {
                          sbOption match
                          {
                            case Some(sb) =>
                            {
                              accumulator.append(sb.mkString)
                              (accumulator,None)
                            }
                            case None =>
                            {
                              (accumulator,Some(new StringBuilder))
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        case _ =>
                        {
                          sbOption.foreach(_.append(char))
                          (accumulator,sbOption)
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }._1.map(_.mkString).toList
 }
```

However, that seems pretty complicated, for what sounds like it should be a simple task. We can use regexes, but those are scary so let's avoid them. In fact, with a little bit of thought this problem actually becomes quite simple.

```
 def extractValuesSimple(s: String) =
 {
    s.split('$'). //Split the string on the $ character
      dropRight(1). //Drops the rightmost item, to handle the case with an odd number of $
      zipWithIndex.filter{case (str, index) => index % 2 == 1}. //Filter out all of the even indexed items, which will always be outside of the matching $
      map{case (str, index) => str}.toList //Remove the indexes from the output
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution enough?

```
scala> val stringToParse = "ignore/me/$aaa$/once-again/ignore/me/$bbb$/still-to-be/ignored"
stringToParse: String = ignore/me/$aaa$/once-again/ignore/me/$bbb$/still-to-be/ignored

scala> val P = """\$([^\$]+)\$""".r
P: scala.util.matching.Regex = \$([^\$]+)\$

scala> P.findAllIn(stringToParse).map{case P(s) => s}.toSeq
res1: Seq[String] = List(aaa, bbb)
```